# How to tell Drupal to look for templates in module directory?

Tags: 7, theming

I'd like to provide template implementation in my module and allow themes to override it. Basically, I add a suggestion by this simplified code:

```
function attach_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__test';
}
```

(I don't want to use hook_theme to add a new theme because I want to reuse preprocess node functions. The theme name are awkward but I don't want to write node_*attach*_% to avoid confusion with node type.)

Then I use hook_theme_registry_alter() to add module path:

```
function attach_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'attach') . '/themes';
  $theme_registry_copy = $theme_registry;
  _theme_process_registry($theme_registry_copy, 'phptemplate', 'theme_engine', 'node', drupal_get_path('module', 'node'));
  $theme_registry += array_diff_key($theme_registry_copy, $theme_registry);
  if (!isset($theme_registry['node']['theme paths'])) {
    $theme_registry['node']['theme paths'] = array();
  }
  if (!isset($theme_registry['node']['theme paths'])) {
    $first_element = array_shift($theme_registry['node']['theme paths']);
    if ($first_element) {
      array_unshift($theme_registry['node']['theme paths'], $first_element, $path);
    }
    else {
      array_unshift($theme_registry['node']['theme paths'], $path);
    }
  }
}
```

However it does not work. That means: the file themes/node--super.tpl.php is not used. It is used only if I copied it to the theme folder.

Comment: Clarification: I want Drupal to look in module directory (and also in theme directories) for a template defined by code (here: node template). I don't want to define a new template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you can save yourself a bit of headache by implementing [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) instead of altering the registry.

I suggest a look at theming_example in the [Examples project](http://drupal.org/project/examples), handily reproduced on [this API doc page](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/theming_example!theming_example.module/7), perhaps with especially helpful code [on this page](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/theming_example!theming_example.module/function/theming_example_list_page/7).

```
function theming_example_list_page() {
  $items = array(
    t('First item'),
    t('Second item'),
    t('Third item'),
    t('Fourth item'),
  );

  // First we'll create a render array that simply uses theme_item_list.
  $title = t("A list returned to be rendered using theme('item_list')");
  $build['render_version'] = array(
    // We use #theme here instead of #theme_wrappers because theme_item_list()
    // is the classic type of theme function that does not just assume a
    // render array, but instead has its own properties (#type, #title, #items).
    '#theme' => 'item_list',
    // '#type' => 'ul',  // The default type is 'ul'
    // We can easily make sure that a css or js file is present using #attached. 
    '#attached' => array('css' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'theming_example') . '/theming_example.css')), 
    '#title' => $title, 
    '#items' => $items, 
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('render-version-list')),
  );

  // Now we'll create a render array which uses our own list formatter,
  // theme('theming_example_list').
  $title = t("The same list rendered by theme('theming_example_list')");
  $build['our_theme_function'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'theming_example_list', 
    '#attached' => array('css' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'theming_example') . '/theming_example.css')), 
    '#title' => $title, 
    '#items' => $items,
  );
  return $build;
}
```

This is all for Drupal 7.

Comment: As I said in the question, I don't want to use hook_theme() because I want to reuse $variables in the node template. Those variables are generated in hook_(pre)process of many modules who don't know the existence of my theme (if I define one).

Comment: The way you define a theme is... with hook_theme(). :-) You can define theming functions in hook_theme(). Name them anything you want. Make shim functions if you want. API docs: "hook_theme_HOOK() ...should only be used if a module needs to override or add to the theme preprocessing for a theme hook it didn't define."

Comment: I don't want to define a theme. If you define your theme 'mynode' instead of reusing 'node', you don't have any variable in your .tpl.php file.

Comment: This doesn't seem true : theme calls are cumulative so implementing `hook_theme` should give you the `$existing` parameter which lets you modify the thing, not overriding it. If it's not the case then perhaps you're hitting a bug.

Comment: @Countzero when you declare a theme node_attach, then all hook_preprocess_node functions won't happen with your new theme. I.e. you don't have anything in your node-attach.tpl.php.

Comment: OK. Seems like I learned something today.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this one works:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array (
    'node__CONTENTTYPE' => array (
      'variables' => array( . . . ),
      'template' => 'node--CONTENTTYPE' ,
      'base hook' => 'node',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Important here is the key '**base hook**'.

Comment: Here's the issue for adding documentation for `base hook`: https://drupal.org/node/2106635

Comment: +1 upvote - this and the derivative answer from batigotix I found to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I like [dashohoxha's solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/82215/12010) of the hook_theme implementation but was not able to get it working. After some more googling I found [a variation that worked nice](https://www.drupal.org/node/715160#comment-9206147) for me:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $theme = array();
  $theme['node__blog_post'] = array(
    'render element' => 'content',
    'base hook' => 'node',
    'template' => 'node--blog_post',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates',
   );
  return $theme;
}
```

Notes: my custom module is called 'mymodule' and my custom content type is called 'blog_post'. The tpl.php that I use is called 'node--blog_post.tpl.php' and it is located in the 'templates' sub folder of my module.

Comment: +1 thanks I found this to work. 
If you're also interested in overriding template.php functions inside your custom module, take a look at: http://snugug.com/musings/override-theme-functions-drupal-7-module/ - I found this to work very well

Answer (score 2):

Here is my snippet to declare views templates stored in the "template" folder of my "custom_module":

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function custom_module_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $extension   = '.tpl.php';
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module');
  $files       = file_scan_directory($module_path . '/templates', '/' . preg_quote($extension) . '$/');

  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $template = drupal_basename($file->filename, $extension);
    $theme    = str_replace('-', '_', $template);
    list($base_theme, $specific) = explode('__', $theme, 2);

    // Don't override base theme.
    if (!empty($specific) && isset($theme_registry[$base_theme])) {
      $theme_info = array(
        'template'   => $template,
        'path'       => drupal_dirname($file->uri),
        'variables'  => $theme_registry[$base_theme]['variables'],
        'base hook'  => $base_theme,
        // Other available value: theme_engine.
        'type'       => 'module',
        'theme path' => $module_path,
      );

      $theme_registry[$theme] = $theme_info;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: saved my time. Also works and required for d8

Answer (score -1):

I asked this once on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835457/drupal-load-view-template-on-module-activation). Basically, you have to implement `hook_theme_registry_alter()` to get your path added to the theme hook template path; then, on `hook_enable()`, you call  [drupal_theme_rebuild()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/drupal_theme_rebuild/7) to clear the theme registry cache and get your path scanned for templates.

Comment: Maybe what's holding you back is just clearing the caches.

Comment: So, basically the same solution. I tried "drush cc all" not less than 50 times, tested it on a new install site  etc. without success. I'll modify and compact my code into a minimal module so that everyone can test.

Comment: `hook_enable()` is invoked when a module is enabled; if the module is already enabled, it must be disabled, and then enabled again.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: iḿ using hook_enable to clear the caches, if it is already installed then user might just clear the caches manually.

Comment: **NO**, -1 points. That solution is so old (2009), I'm not even sure it was meant for D7. While your old solution is tailored for Views, it is not ideal for non-Views situations where developers may want to pack for more than 1 default template per theme key in their modules. Imagine implementing your solution for 100 dynamic theme suggestions for a single theme key. Applied outside of a Views context I would call your solution a counter-pattern.

Comment: Confirming - that is a D6 solution (https://drupal.org/node/645716) for a D7 question. Hence the -1 stays as a warning on the road to weary travelers. D6 actually had a better solution for that (just modifying theme paths) and the module would get scanned for template suggestions as well - and I mean, all template suggestions - but that trick is no longer valid in D7.