# Let's Make A Module that Generates a Block that uses a Template in D6

Tags: 6, blocks, theming

#### A Module (sites/all/modules/custom/reminders/reminders.module)

```
<?php
// $Id$

function reminders_block($op='list', $delta=0, $edit=array()) {
    switch ($op) {
        case 'list':
            $blocks[0]['info'] = t('Reminders Block');
            $blocks[0]['cache'] = BLOCK_NO_CACHE;
            return $blocks;
        case 'view':
            $block['content'] = 'dummy text that is replaced by block-moduleName.tpl.php';
            return $block;
    }   
}
```

#### A Template (sites/all/modules/custom/reminders/block-reminders.tpl.php)

```
<?php
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module','reminders') . '/reminders.css');
?>
<h1>Hey! Don't forget!!</h1>
```

#### A Mystery

This has fluctuated between working and not working. I see lots of modules using this tidy file structure where the .module and .tpl.php can live together. That's what I'm hoping for. Devel's Theme Developer module told me to use `block-reminders.tpl.php` and from what I've read it's okay to put the template file next to the module instead of all the way in the theme somewhere.

#### A Few More Things

- I cleared the theme registry

#### The Question

What's missing so that I can use this more elegant method of developing modules? I wanted to let drupal cascade with as many defaults as possible so there's not as much code.

Comment: Are you asking how to get Drupal to detect your template files in your module directory? This has been asked quite some times. You could use this answer which I gave some time ago: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46476/how-to-use-another-themes-template-file/46506#46506. That answer is for D7, but should work for D6 as well.

Comment: I think that's obvious.. but okay. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I've never done this without invoking `hook_theme()` (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).

Comment: @WrayBowling The reason it doesn't work is because Drupal doesn't automagically pick up your module path when it searches for template files (tpl). You need to notify Drupal about where your templates lies. **As a sidenote**, the `drupal_add_css()` call should ideally not be in your template. Add it through a preprocess hook instead. Drupal follows the [PAC model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control).